# Generate json from query result

Tags: json, postgresql

I have table `locations`:

```
country, city
USA, New York
USA, San Francisco
UK, London
UK, Bristol
Poland, Warsaw
```

Is there any way using postgres functions to generate json like this:

```
{
    'USA': ['New York', 'San Francisco'],
    'UK': ['London', 'Bristol'],
    'Poland': ['Warsaw']
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5eb071a5173ad3734dfaa727dc8e68d2)

```
SELECT 
   json_object_agg(country, cities)    -- 2
FROM (
   SELECT
      country,
      json_agg(city) as cities         -- 1
   FROM
       locations
   GROUP BY country                    -- 1
) s
```

1. Aggregate the `city` elements by their `country` into one JSON array using `json_agg()`
2. After that you are able to aggregate all rows into one JSON object using `json_object_agg()`